# AssetsLibrary with UIImagePicker - ELCImagePickerController

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller

I was wondering if anyone else has used the following in their iOS applications.

https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController

Basically it is a clone of the UIImagePicker using the using the AssetsLibrary that is available with iOS 4.0.

For the most part I like it, but I ran into two issues.

1) When on a device, it take quite a while when there are more that 200 images in a Library.  While it works when once it loads, it takes quite a bit longer than I would ideally like.

2) When selecting some images, it brings it over with a different orientation that is shown on the screen.  (looks like that happens most with pictures I took from the iPhone) I even seen it turn an image upside down.

I am just curious if anyone else has used this, and if so, were they able to overcome these issues.

Comment: Hi, as u have used it ,then is it possible to get images from synced albums in ipad using ELCimagepickrcontroller

Comment: Yes, when I was using it, and album that was synced with the iPad showed up for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding orientation you can use the "ALAssetPropertyOrientation" and get the image orientation and than get any orientation that you may need.

Below are the orientation that iOS support

```
typedef enum {
UIImageOrientationUp,            // default orientation
UIImageOrientationDown,          // 180 deg rotation
UIImageOrientationLeft,          // 90 deg CCW
UIImageOrientationRight,         // 90 deg CW
UIImageOrientationUpMirrored,    // as above but image mirrored along other axis. horizontal flip
UIImageOrientationDownMirrored,  // horizontal flip
UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored,  // vertical flip
UIImageOrientationRightMirrored, // vertical flip
} UIImageOrientation;
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Load first 100 images, update GUI and load other in background.
2) UIImage have property imageOrientation